# Does get_template_part() content gets parsed if it's not executed?

Tags: page-template, get-template-part

My page templates are currently built up as shown in first example but I really don't like that half of the template is *just sitting there*, not being used and takes the server resources for no good reason.

**Does everything in both examples gets parsed by server, emphasis
 on `get_template_part()`?**

---

```
<?php

//Page template

if( $something ) {

    // 1000 lines of code
}
else if( $something_else ) {

    // 1000 lines of code
}

?>
```

---

***versus***

---

```
<?php

// Page template

if( $something ) {

    // Template with 1000 lines of code
    get_template_part( 'lib/template', 'option-a' );
}
else if( $something_else ) {

    // Template with 1000 lines of code
    get_template_part( 'lib/template', 'option-b' );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if `$something` or `$something_else` are true, otherwise the code will jump to the next argument.

Comment: I have a feeling you kept executing the code in mind.. How about parsing? I know for sure that the whole code in _first example_ gets parsed, even if it's in _false_ block. How are things with `get_template_part()` content?

Comment: `get_template_part` is a function – if the function is never run, the code is never executed